# Hibernate @OneToOne bidirectional causes redundant select query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities: Address and Customer. They have ont-to-one relationship and bidirectional.

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Customer customer;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;

    ...
}
```

Then I execute the following code to select Customer by Id.

```
entityManager.find(Customer.class, 1L);
```

I find two queries will be generated. It's so confusing. I think only the first query is enough to get both Customer and Address entities.

```
select * from Customer customer0_ left outer join Address address1_ on customer0_.address_id=address1_.id where customer0_.id=?
select * from Customer customer0_ left outer join Address address1_ on customer0_.address_id=address1_.id where customer0_.address_id=?
```

Does anyone meet this problem? Can you point me out if there is some mistake in the code?

Comment: can you add `@JoinColumn(name = "foreign_key_in_customer")` above address in Customer class. And why are you doing `new Address();`?

Comment: Did you try with @JoinColumn annotation and see the result?

Comment: I would guess that there is some more code after `find`, which creates the second `SELECT`. Usually there is only one `SELECT` for a `find`.

Comment: @NamanGala I have added JoinColumn and still got two select

Comment: Did you debug your code? Are both the selects fired at the time of find?

Comment: @TobiasLiefke I have removed other code, and only left `find`. Still got the same result.

Comment: @NamanGala Yes, the two selects are printed out within a single `find`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define at least one of your `OneToOne` as `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`. The default is `FetchType.EAGER` - thats why he tries to load `Address.customer` in the second statement.

And I wouldn't use `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` for both directions - that can lead to problems as well. Usually only the owning side of the link will use `CascadeType.ALL`.